# Saving Array of Array in Mysql using Active Record Code Igniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to save a Form Data in Mysql. But nested array is causing problem.

```
Array ( [name] => Custom Project 
        [number] => 08883 
        [key] => Array ( [0] => Server Cost 
                         [1] => Domain Cost 
                         [2] => Design Charges, 
                       ) 
        [value] => Array ( [0] => 098 
                           [1] => 765 
                           [2] => 787 
                          ) 
      )
```

I am using `$this->db->insert('invoice',$array)` and it is inserting data fine without the nested array.

So is there a way I can separate this nested array from above array and then save this nested array into another table having only two columns `key` and `value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the very simple approach, I pushed one array to another because the result was to be processed in Codeigniter insert method.

```
//Item description
        $description=$_POST['key'];

        //item amount
        $amount=$_POST['value'];

        $big_array=array();

        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($description); $i++){

                $small_array=array('description'=>$description[$i],'amount'=>$amount[$i]);

                array_push($big_array,$small_array);
            }

        //adding data into model
        $this->my_Model->InsertData($big_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `array_combine` to create the key pair value:

```
function save_value($array)
{
    $key_value = array_combine($array['key'], $array['value']);
    $this->db->insert('table_name', $key_value);
}
```

Comment: It didn't help but I figured out myself